# Restrict the azure function to reprocess the events which are thrown the exception while processing them

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to build an event trigger azure function. After reading the event it will have some SQL operations to perform.

While performing the SQL operations the query timeout is happening and function throws error, due to this my transaction rollback will happen. We handled retry mechanism for the transient error with 3 times but, even after that the Lock request timeout happening and function throws exception.

Then this event is again picked up for processing. How to restrict the function to not to pick this event again?

```
def write_to_database():
    with self.connection.db_engine().begin() as conn:
       self.delete_rows()
       self.update_table()
       self.check_msg()
```

Lock request timeout at delete_rows() causing the exception and the message is reprocessed again and again.

Comment: at eventgrid level, you can specify the retry to be exactly one then even if it s fail it wont reprocess the message